# OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility - Service Error on Migration Summary

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I have downloaded opshub tool for the migration, trying to migrate from on premises to visualstydio team service. Getting error On the migration summary page with error message:

***"Unable to communicate with the required process opshubtfsservice.Because probably it is not running. Restart application & try again"***

I verified the opshub service is running as local service. I tried to restart & tried with Network service/local account etc. But no lock.

Can you please help me on this here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your machine is behind a proxy and all traffic in-out is being routed through it. (Including the communication of local traffic)
You will have to bypass local addresses from the proxy as well as enable OVSMU to communicate through the proxy.

Please refer the ***C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\Other_Resources\Resources\ProxyUtility.zip*** to configure OVSMU to utilize your proxy. There should be a user guide document which lists the steps.Keep the bypass local address value as default.