# Unable to communicate to the required process opshubtfsservice. Because its already running

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

[image]---------------------------

### Error

Unable to communicate with the required process opshubtfsservice. Because it is probably not running. Restart application and try again.

OK
I have already so many times tried to restart the service and application as well but it couldn't. This problem occurring only in server.

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36170444/3627522

It seems that your machine is behind a proxy and all traffic in-out is being routed through it. (Including the communication of local traffic) You will have to bypass local addresses from the proxy as well as enable OVSMU to communicate through the proxy.

Please refer the **C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\Other_Resources\Resources\ProxyUtility.zip** to configure OVSMU to utilize your proxy. There should be a user guide document which lists the steps.Keep the bypass local address value as default

Comment: I was mapping all the users. But its still migration doesn't have changeset history details with their corresponding user name. It displays only with who s running migration tool . Can you help me on this ?